# TCPserver делфи передать текст

Tags: delphi

Подскажите, как передать с сервера, из `TMemo` или `TLabel` текст в клиент `TLabel`, используя `TCPServer` и `TCPClient`?

Answer (score 1):

В `Delphi` есть готовый пример `NetChat` который показывает как работать с соккетами.

изучите его.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.

Comment: дело в том что у меня эмбаркадеро хе8, там имеются ошибки, можно ли пример?

Comment: после того как клиент подключился к серверу, сервер должен из едита передать текст в леэбл в клиент, вот и все, с клиента на сервер могу а тут нужно получить отбратно?